# Generic list deleting non pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, generic-list, delete-operator

I have a generic list with a template

```
template<class t>
class GenericList {
    //the data is storeed in a chained list, this is not really important.
    struct c_list { t data; c_list* next; ...constructor... };

public:
    bool isDelete;
    GenericList() : isDelete(false) {...}

    void add(t d) {
        c_list* tmp = new c_list(d, first->next);
        //this is not really important again...
    }

    ~GenericList() {
        c_list* tmp = first;
        c_list* tmp2;
        while(tmp->next!=NULL) {
            if (isDelete) { delete tmp->data; } //important part
            tmp2=tmp->next;
            delete tmp;
            tmp=tmp2;

        }
    }
};
```

**The important part is the isDelete**
 *This is only a sample code*

I need this because I want to store data like this:

```
GenericList<int> list;
list.add(22);list.add(33);
```

and also

```
GenericList<string*> list;
list.add(new string("asd")); list.add(new string("watta"));
```

---

The problem if I store only `<int>` the compiler said that I cannot delete non pointer variables, but I don't want to in this case. How can I solve this?
*when I store `<int*>` there is no compiler error...*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without changing much your code, I would solve your problem as

```
template<class t>
class GenericList 
{
  //same as before

  //add this function template
   template<typename T>
   void delete_if_pointer(T & item) {}  //do nothing: item is not pointer

   template<typename T>
   void delete_if_pointer(T* item) { delete item; } //delete: item is pointer

  ~GenericList() {
       c_list* tmp = first;
       c_list* tmp2;
       while(tmp->next!=NULL) {
          delete_if_pointer(tmp->data); // call the function template
          tmp2=tmp->next;
          delete tmp;
          tmp=tmp2;
       }
   }
};
```

---

EDIT: I just noticed that @ildjarn has provided similar solution. However there is one interesting difference: my solution does NOT require you to mention the type of `data` when calling the function template; the compiler automatically deduces it. @ildjarn's solution, however, requires you to mention the type explicitly; the compiler *cannot* deduce the type in his solution.

Comment: @ildjarn: I'm using `&` anyway. That is enough to avoid copy!

Answer (score 1):

I would create a nested struct template inside your class to help:

```
template<typename U>
struct deleter
{
    static void invoke(U const&) { }
};

template<typename U>
struct deleter<U*>
{
    static void invoke(U* const ptr) { delete ptr; }
};
```

Then change the line that was using `isDelete` from

```
if (isDelete) { delete tmp->data; }
```

to

```
if (isDelete) { deleter<t>::invoke(tmp->data); }
```

Answer (score 0):

`delete` on an `int` makes a program ill-formed, so the compiler will reject it, even though the `delete` would never be reached.

What you want is only possible if you switch from "bare" pointers to smart pointers such as `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`; those handle memory management for you, without explicit `delete`.